# Checkbox in panel header to control visibility of panel content?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a checkbox in a panel header, which I want to show the panel.

```
<div class='panel'>
    <div class='panel-header'> 
        <label for='check1'>
            <input id='check1' type='checkbox' value='on'>
            Checkbox Label
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class='panel-content'>
    </div>
</div>
```

I cannot seem to build a selector that will select `.panel-content` and make it visible only when `#check1` is checked.  I need to be able to select a child `.panel-content` of an element `.panel`, where `.panel` has a child input that's checked.

Comment: I don't think thats going to work, since .panel-content is neither a sibling or child to #check1. Is it possible to rewrite the html structure or use javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Check this ;)
Working: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Louxsjxd/1/)

```
$("#check1").on("change",function(){
   var panelContent = $(this).parent().parent().parent().children(".panel-content");
   if(this.checked) {
       $(panelContent).show();
   }else{
       $(panelContent).hide();
   }
});

// Get #check1 .panel-content
var panelCheckbox = $(".panel").children(".panel-header").children("label").children("#check1");
var panelContent;
if($(panelCheckbox).prop("checked") = true){
   panelContent = $(panelCheckbox).parent().parent().parent().children(".panel-content");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o16v3a5j/3/

I hope this was what you were trying to achieve?

**First:** I add a JS listener:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
      document.querySelector('#check1').addEventListener('change', reactToCheckbox);
});
```

**Second:** change the `panel-content`'s `id` every time the listener responds to a change in the checkbox:

```
function reactToCheckbox(){
   if(check1.checked){
        var element = document.getElementById("panel-content").id = 'panel-content-show';           return false;
   }
   else{
      var element = document.getElementById("panel-content-show").id = 'panel-content';             return false;
   }
};
```

Hope that helped, otherwise good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can achieve this with pure CSS only is by changing your HTML by removing the `checkbox` wrapper `div.panel-header` and also outside the `label`, *you don't really need to wrap `label`s around `input`as long as you have the `for=""` attributein the `label`*,so that the `checkbox` is on the same level with `div.pnael-content` and not deeper nested.

[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/rgjL4yoj/1/)

```css
.panel-content {
  display: none;
  padding: 5px;
  background: skyblue;
}
#check1:checked ~ .panel-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class='panel'>
  <div class='panel-header'></div>
  <input id='check1' type='checkbox' checked>
  <label for='check1'>Checkbox Label</label>
  <div class='panel-content'>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium quis nesciunt et, maiores sint voluptatum enim earum non illum temporibus velit reprehenderit dignissimos cum minima! Voluptatem voluptas delectus fugiat molestiae.
  </div>
</div>
```